# Making an AI model that converts songs into a game level?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I want to create an AI that coverts songs into beatsaber levels (It's a VR game). A beatsaber level can be stored as a array of "blocks" that looks like this:

```
{
  "time": 1.25,
  "direction": "up",
  "hand": "right",
  "pos_x": 0,
  "pos_y": 1
}
```

So the AI should convert songs into a level that has a lot of these blocks like the above. So far I have just done AIs that solve classification problems. But this problem has a generative nature. Does anyone know how to approch this kind of problem. Maybe with links that lead me in the right direction.

I have enough training data of already existing levels and songs. So that is no problem. I just need to know how the architecture of an AI like this looks like and how it should work.

Also I would like to make this with tensorflow if its possible. But other technologies are also fine.

Here is a link that should give you a better understanding of the game. The above JSON example resembles one block in the level. So the AI should generate an array of these blocks, and therefore generating a whole level.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JVXv2ySToU

Comment: You need to define your problem much better before you write any code. You need to define what makes a "good"/enjoyable level so that you can optimize for that. You need to define what it means for a level to be a good fit to the music so that you can optimize for that. You need to maybe come up with a representation of music that's well suited to computing that goodness-of-fit. Then you can *start* thinking about "AI".

Comment: I already know what makes a level "good" and enjoyable, and I already have an idea on how to optimize for that. My question is more about how to write an AI that "understands" music and "generates" data that fits to the music.

Comment: That's far too broad a question to be on topic here. Deciding what it is to "understand" music is something you need to do on your end. Deciding what knobs on your generation algorithm to tweak based on that understanding, likewise. Building that algorithm, _again_, likewise.

Comment: I found exactly what I needed here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.06891.pdf

Comment: Great! I'm glad you found what you need. Consider closing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a paper about a very similar AI:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.06891.pdf

They use **two** Neural Networks, the first one extracts audio features like Drums and decides when to place blocks **(timing of blocks)** and the other one decides how the blocks are arranged **(direction of blocks)**.